# Why validate with ASP.NET Validators?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, textbox

I'm making my first real ASP page and I need to validate a time of day in 14 different text box fields (both that there is a value present and that the value is ultimately between 0:00:00-23:59:59). I was thinking it would be much easier to write a validation function and then explicitly call it at some point (i.e. when a user hits "submit", or in the TextChanged event handler) instead of adding in either 14 custom validators or 14 range (or RegEx) validators and 14 required field validators.

I figure the validators must exist for a reason, but using them to validate in this context looks like doing substantially more work than not using them and I can't see any advantage to justify it.

Is there an advantage to the ASP.NET validators that I'm not seeing? Making 14 copies of the same validator in the ASP markup just doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: Most of the time there's only one date on the page to be validated, or maybe a start and end date.  Your validation function approach seems sensible.

Comment: Why are you duplicating 14 text boxes ? It's not a criticism just a question :)

Comment: It's a form to set the open and close times for support phone numbers - every day needs a start and a stop time, and they wanted it so that the days could all have different phone open/close hours.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://blog.devshed.nl/2011/01/aspnet-compile-time-supported_06.html?m=1). It might  give you some ideas to improve the maintainability of your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon some pondering, my best idea for this scenario would be a `WebUserControl` that will have a `TextBox` and a `CustomFieldValidator` or `RequiredFieldValidator`. Then it would just be a matter of Drag and Drop the `WebUserControl` into your page. Here is a simple example using a `RequiredFieldValidator`.

**ASCX File (WebControl):**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SelfValidationTextBox.ascx.cs" Inherits="SelfValidationTextBox" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="* Required Field"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

**ASPX File:**

```
<%@ Register Src="SelfValidationTextBox.ascx" TagName="SelfValidationTextBox" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <uc1:SelfValidationTextBox ID="SelfValidationTextBox1" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <uc1:SelfValidationTextBox ID="SelfValidationTextBox2" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <uc1:SelfValidationTextBox ID="SelfValidationTextBox3" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <uc1:SelfValidationTextBox ID="SelfValidationTextBox4" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <uc1:SelfValidationTextBox ID="SelfValidationTextBox5" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this would be a good work around, and you can even do as you suggested using the CustomFieldValidators and just one function using this solution as well.

[image: Result of using RequiredFieldValidators in a WebUserControl]

Answer (score 0):

If possible stay with ASP.NET validators.

Its easy for others to see what you are doing in terms of:

- applied rules
- localization
- client side uproach

I would also worry about repeated code if I needed to handle the same stuff 14 times. But this is true even if you write the code for the textboxes. I would place the controlls (textboxes and validators) on the page from codebehind in a dynamic way. This is not the easiest part of ASP.NET, but it will help you on the long run.

See here how you do it.
http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2008/06/26/123391.aspx

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I'd primarily treat ASP.Net validators as 'server-side' validation - exactly as you say - "after submit"/Postback.

In your specific case, if you require the same routine for 14 boxes (required + range), the advantage of using ASP.Net validators for **client side** validation can be "replaced" by other client side options (e.g. jQuery validation) so that you can (re)gain it and still maintain server-side validation (and accomplish your one-server-side-routine for 14 uses - aka "custom validation").

The "upside" of client side validation (whether through ASP.Net validators or some other framework) is that entries are validated as they are being provided by the user (no postback/submit), and same on submission itself - there is no server work/postback until validation on the client side is accomplished (you're handing off work to client and not all on server, and, not having to wire 14 validators doing the same routine).

Answer (score 0):

I would use Repeater control and bind it to the list of objects that will hold the data for each item. You can do it all easy and quick in code behind and validation will work both client and server side, in other words it will work if user turns off javascript.

Define a data class, for example :

```
  public class InputDataItem
  {
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public InputDataItem()
    {
    }

    public InputDataItem(string text)
    {
      this.Text = text;
    }
  }
```

and markup :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptInputs" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbxInput" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqfValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbxInput" ErrorMessage="* Required!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

and bind repeater and get values entered by user with this code

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    var data = new List<InputDataItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      data.Add(new InputDataItem("Item " + i.ToString()));
    }
    rptInputs.DataSource = data;
    rptInputs.DataBind();
  }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (IsValid)
  {
    var data = new List<InputDataItem>();
    foreach (RepeaterItem rit in rptInputs.Items)
    {
      Control cnt = rit.FindControl("tbxInput");
      if (cnt != null && cnt is TextBox)
        data.Add(new InputDataItem((cnt as TextBox).Text));
    }
    /// here you have list of POCO objects filled with user input
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to do something that is already done? Asp.net validators provide both client and server side validation. DRY - Dont Repeat Yourself. Just use ASP.net Validators

Comment: In this specific scenario, I would not want to use 14 customs validators myself. He says "I figure the validators must exist for a reason, but using them to validate in this context looks like doing substantially more work than not using them and I can't see any advantage to justify it."

Comment: Well eventhough, he is going to write 14 custom functions( client and server side), he will get the advantage of automatic invocation (validation), error message display, and stuff. I would use ASP.net Validators.  Any way, you is going to write 14 different validations himself

Comment: He would have to write just one validation function, and validate each textbox with the same function. He would, however, have to call it from 14 different places at the most.

Comment: I was actually just going to write 1 validation function that rolls through all the TextBox controls and validates the contents of each text box when the user hits "submit". If they all were valid, the operation continues. If anything failed, I stop the operation and make a hidden label appear with the error message at the top of the page.